# How to aggregate names of a list() in R

Tags: r

I have a list created like this:

```
$`a`
[1] 3
$`a`
[1] 15
$`a`
[1] 30
$`b`
[1] 3
$`b`
[1] 9
$`c`
[1] 15
$`c`
[1] 21
```

I wonder if there is any method that I could aggregate same $ in the list() together, so that it would look like:

```
$`a`
[1] 3 15 30
$`b`
[1] 3 9
$`c`
[1] 15 21
```

Thank you very much for your kind answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be

```
unstack(stack(l))
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5

$c
[1] 6
```

**data**

```
l <- list(a = 1, a = 2, a = 3, b = 4, b = 5, c = 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

We `unlist` the `list` (assuming there is a single list element and `split` it based on the `names` of the `list`

```
split(unlist(lst1, use.names = FALSE), names(lst1))
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b
#[1] 4 5

#$c
#[1] 6
```

---

For a general case, i.e. elements with `length` greater than 1

```
with(stack(lst1), split(values, ind))
```

However, `stack` would be a bit slow for large datasets, so, in that case, use `split` with `lengths`

```
split(unlist(lst1), rep(names(lst1), lengths(lst1)))
```

#### Benchmarks

Benchmarks on a larger dataset

```
lst2 <- rep(lst1, 1e5)
system.time(split(unlist(lst2, use.names = FALSE), names(lst2)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.067   0.009   0.076 
system.time(unstack(stack(lst2)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.696   0.031   0.681 
system.time(with(stack(lst2), split(values, ind)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.447   0.027   0.475 
system.time(split(unlist(lst2), rep(names(lst2), lengths(lst2))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.100   0.005   0.105
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(a = 1, a = 2, a = 3, b = 4, b = 5, c = 6)
```